# Magento 2, how to edit 'Text-area' to 'select-list' in sale order page?

Tags: magento2.2, adminhtml, shipping, sales-order

Using `magento 2.2`, `admin`, `sale->order->ship`. I want to change the *text-area* of **shipment comment** to *select list* .

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For shipment comments, magento2 uses the same comment form as order. You can modify the form by overriding the view.phtml from below location:

> /vendor/magento/module-sales/view/adminhtml/templates/order/comments/view.phtml

You need to add below code for select option(replace the options according to your requirement):

```
<select name="comment[comment]" id="history_comment">
    <option value="This is 1st test comment">This is first test comment</option>
    <option value="This is 2nd test comment">This is second test comment</option>
</select>
```

Instead of

```
<textarea name="comment[comment]" class="admin__control-textarea" rows="3" cols="5" id="history_comment"></textarea>
```